# What does "char *accum(const char *source);" mean in C?

Tags: c

I was looking at some programming practices in Codewars and most of them start with only this line to work with:

```
char *accum(const char *source);
```

I've never seen this syntax before, what exactly does this do? I assume it assigned accum to source, but I've tried printing accum and it hits me with this error:

```
undefined reference to `accum'
```

Comment: This is the signature of a function. It tells your current file how is this function supposed to work (parameters + return type)

Comment: Ohhhh. I feel like such an idiot right now, I thought this was regular syntax inside of a function. Thanks.

Comment: if in doubt: https://cdecl.org is your friend (try `char *accum(const char*)`.)

Comment: (and that would also be valid inside a function to declare a variable `accum` which is a function)

Comment: If you've never seen this syntax before it is time to go to a library/a book store and get yourself a C book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a signature of a function. It allows you to use a function which is defined later in your code.

If you want to declare a function that takes a `float` in argument and return an `int` you have to write this piece of code : `int myFunction(float arg);`

So here, you have the signature of a function that returns a `char *` and take an argument of type `const char *`